# html5 - drawing multiple circles - each filled with different images

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

Alright so ive looked around and found a code that will successfulyl enable me to draw a circle on canvas and use that circle as a mask for my image.

The code looks like this: (codus to the real creater that i dont know)

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('your_canvas').getContext("2d");

ctx.arc(100,100, 50, 0, Math.PI*2,true); // you can use any shape
ctx.clip();

var img = new Image();
img.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
    ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0, 200, 300);
}, true);
img.src="/path/to/image.jpg";
```

Lets assume I want to have 5 different circles all with different images and all and each positioned differently.

Anyone got an idea on how id go about that?

Comment: In short, if the above code works for 1 image, use it 5 times for 5 images. Or create a function with parameters for the values that change for each image. I think the main thing missing in the code above is the use of `save()` and `restore()`, to allow the code to be used more than once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep the code short, create a function with parameters for the settings that will change from image to image.

**Reusable function:**

```
function drawImageCircle(ctx, circleX, circleY, radius,
                              imageX, imageY, imageWidth, imageHeight, imageUrl) {

    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function(){
        ctx.save();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(circleX, circleY, radius, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
        ctx.clip();
        ctx.drawImage(this, imageX, imageY, imageWidth, imageHeight);
        ctx.restore();
    };
    img.src = imageUrl;
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('your_canvas').getContext("2d");

drawImageCircle(ctx, 100,100, 50,  0,0,     200,300, 'image1.jpg');
drawImageCircle(ctx, 400,400, 50,  300,300, 200,300, 'image2.jpg');
```

The use of `save()` and `restore()` is important when doing this more than once.

Comment: I like your idea of a reusable function, but to get it to work you'll probably have to do image preloading and feed it the actual images instead of just the imageUrl. BTW, img.src=imageUrl should go after img.onload ;)

Comment: @markE: Admittedly, without preloading, the images will be drawn asynchronously (in a somewhat random order), which might not be acceptable if they overlap (causing the wrong one to sometimes be on top). Good catch about the order of `img.src` and `img.onload`! Thanks for pointing that out! I updated it.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, pretty much what Matt said...

Here is code and a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/Vu2Fm/

You can improve this code by using an image preloader to load all 5 of your images prior to drawing on the canvas.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    var img1=new Image();
    img1.onload=function(){

        var img2=new Image();
        img2.onload=function(){

            // draw a clipping circle and then an image to clip
            ctx.save();
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.strokeStyle="blue";
            ctx.arc(100, 100, 50, 0 , 2 * Math.PI, false);
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.clip();
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(100, 100, 50, 0 , 2 * Math.PI, false);
            ctx.drawImage(img1,10,0);
            ctx.restore();

            // draw a second clipping circle and then an image to clip
            ctx.save();
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.strokeStyle="green";
            ctx.arc(275, 100, 75, 0 , 2 * Math.PI, false);
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.clip();
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.drawImage(img2,150,0);
            ctx.restore();

        }
        img2.src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/139992952/coffee.png";
    }
    img1.src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/139992952/house%20vector.png";

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=400 height=250></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey Mark - thanks for the comment - makes all sence to me and could surely work for me as an alternative to the more sleek solutions below